# LinkedIn shares API-v2 returns scrambled shares

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am fully confused with the logic LinkedIn Shares API have in place, because what I read from the documentation about the shares [LinkedIn API shares documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api#retrieve) it mentions that all posts are ordered based on created time and we can paginate by specifying start=(100, 200, 300 ,.... n)to get old posts. But that seems to be not true, see the scenarios below.

I perform Shares API calls to get latest posts using 
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sharesPerOwner=1000&count=100&start=0&AccessToke={token}`

**Scenario 1**
 
 
 -- API call: *start=0, count=100*

-- result set: 100 posts, they are ordered by createdTime.
posts are shown from years {2018 ... 2017 ... 2016 ...}. To be noted that result set does not return all posts from 2018, 2017 ..., it just cherrypicks from each year and stacks them.

 
 
**Scenario 2**
 
 
 -- API call: *start=100, count=100*

-- result set: 100 posts, ordered by createdTime, posts starts to appear again from {2018 ..., 2017 ..., 2016 ...}, but they are the missing ones that were missed from the first scenario (not repeated post).

What I would expect from the the first scenario API call would be show all latest results (2018) and I should be able to paginate (start=100, 200 ..) to reach to older ones until 2017 and so on. 
 
 
I would be super happy if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: also asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337438/incorrect-sorting-on-retrieve-shares-via-api-linkedin-com-v2-shares and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816530/why-order-is-not-working-on-v2-shares-endpoint

Comment: found an answer to this? For me not even scenario 1 works :-/