# Incorrect sorting on retrieve shares via api.linkedin.com/v2/shares

Tags: linkedin-api

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-shares), shares are **ordered by creation time** with the most recent share being the first.
But when I request shares, they received with **sorting by last modified time**.

***Example:***
https://www.linkedin.com/company/cadencepcb/

Request:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?owners=urn:li:organization:28610896&q=owners&sharesPerOwner=10&start=0"
```

Response: receive list of shares with this sequence:

> Created: 05/27/2019 8:00pm Modified: 05/27/2019 8:00pm
>
> Created: 06/19/2018 1:00pm Modified: 05/27/2019 3:58pm
>
> Created: 05/27/2019 1:00pm Modified: 05/27/2019 1:01pm
>
> Created: 05/14/2018 1:00pm Modified: 05/27/2019 11:10am
>
> Created: 06/27/2018 2:01pm Modified: 05/27/2019 5:28am
>
> Created: 12/03/2018 2:05pm Modified: 05/27/2019 3:45am
>
> Created: 05/14/2018 8:15pm Modified: 05/27/2019 12:43am

**Question:** how to receive shares ordered by creation time with the most recent share being the first?

Comment: also asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816530/why-order-is-not-working-on-v2-shares-endpoint and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488075/linkedin-shares-api-v2-returns-scrambled-shares