# Why order is not working on /v2/shares endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

At hootsuite.com we are using `v2/shares` to create reports for multiple social profiles over large periods of time.

The documentation for that endpoint specifies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner) that: "Shares are ordered by creation time".

at the moment, when I go to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:15100279&sharesPerOwner=500&start=290

I'll see `"activity": "urn:li:activity:6537431951580684288" with createdTime 1558645236755` between two other shares that both have bigger `createTime` (`1559217643294` and `1559131242301`)

This means that the creation time is not the order.

If the order has been changed on `lastModified` time, please suggest a method to paginate through shares up to a last known share fetched 1 day ago, while guaranteeing no new shares were missed.

Comment: Hi @mihaicc have you already take a look at the [UGC Post API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api#find-ugc-posts-by-authors)?

Comment: Yes, not what I need

Comment: Linkedin is working on a fix: https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/14250

Comment: Has it been fixed?